# Why is my case statement not working with a calculation while using signed over punch?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to go against "Signed Over Punch" using the following query:

```
SELECT 
CASE when substring(MyField,16,1)='C' then cast(substring(MyField,9,7)+'0' AS decimal(20,2)*-1 FROM MyTable
```

Here's some sample data:

```
0000069A0000006C00000000@0000000@
```

From the above data, the position starts at 16 ("C") with a length of 1
And the other starts at position 9 (0) with a length of 7

But I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 139
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

Desired Output:
00000063 (The C = 3)

What am I doing wrong?

Please refer to this page for reference for signed over punch:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_overpunch

Comment: You have `* -1`? Mean `) -1` instead?

Comment: Your [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) is missing an `END`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx). This code:

```
[..snip..] then cast(substring(MyField,9,7)+'0' AS decimal(20,2)*-1
```

is executing as if it had been written

```
[..snip..]  then cast(...) AS (decimal(20,2) * -1)
                              ^------------------^
```

You're not multiplying the result of the cast, you're trying to mutiply the `decimal(20,2)`, which is NOT a multiplicable value.

Try

```
then (cast(substring(MyField,9,7)+'0' AS decimal(20,2)) * -1
     ^------------------------------------------------^
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix it or not, but you are missing a closing parenthesis. You are also missing the END statement I recommend indenting things like this to make it easier to spot these problems.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN substring(MyField,16,1)='C' 
       THEN cast(substring(MyField,9,7)+'0' AS decimal(20,2))*-1 
    END
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try  so:

```
SELECT CASE when substring(MyField,16,1)='C' then cast(substring(MyField,9,7)+'0' AS decimal(20,2)) *-1  end FROM MyTable
```

The problems were a missing " ) " at the defore " *-1 " and a missing "end" to terminate the case when condition.

With these 2 fix the result for your example '0000069A0000006C00000000@0000000@' is -60.00.